# Ember how to catch the action 'ended' from html5 video tag on a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an hbs file with html5 video tag:

```
<video id="externalVideo" controls loop>
    <source src="../assets/videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

and I'm trying to trigger an action when the video ends and handle the event on the template's controller but I just can't seem to catch the event on the controller, how can I do this?

Versions:

- ember-cli: 1.13.8
- ember: 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

**[edit: This answer will not work with non-bubbling events, see my other answer]**

You have three options, from best to worst:

1. Using the `{{action 'videoEnded' on='ended'}}`. That should generate a regular action you can use in your controller or route's `actions: {}`.
2. Adding the `ended` event to the list of [events that Ember will watch automatically](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names):

   ```
   customEvents: {
     ended: 'videoEnded'
   }
   ```

   This `customEvents` must be passed to the application at creation (at the same place you pass `rootElement`). The specifics depend on your exact boot process, whether you're using ember-cli, …

   Once properly configured, ember will listen to `ended` events, and look for a function named `videoEnded` on your views or components.
3. Manual event handlers (not recommended unless you are creating an addon or cannot use either 1. or 2. for some reason).

   ```
   init: function () {
       this._super();
       this._videoEnded = this.videoEnded.bind(this);
   },
   registerEvents: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
       this.get('element').addEventListener('ended', this._videoEnded, false);
   }),
   unregisterEvents: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function () {
       this.get('element').removeEventListener('ended', this._videoEnded, false);
   }),
   videoEnded: function (evt) { Ember.run(function () {
       console.log('Video ended');
   })}
   ```

   Told you it would be a bit messy. In `init` we create a bound version of the handler so `this` will have the correct value when it is called. Then we register the event once Ember has created the DOM element, and unregister it during the teardown process.

   Lastly, we enclose the handler in a [run loop](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/applications/run-loop/) to ensure Ember will detect property changes and run triggers and bindings correctly.

Comment: I'm using ember-cli 1.13.8 and I had already tried `{{action 'videoEnded' on='ended'}}` but it doesn't work, the action `videoEnded` on the controller is never called.

Comment: I'm also trying to add the `customEvents` but the action is still never called.

Comment: with customEvents, it's not an action, it's a function directly on the view (not the controller), and outside `actions`.

Comment: Ok, I just saw something important I had neglected: the `ended` event **does not bubble**. That means methods 1) and 2) will not work. And method 3) needs to be tweaked to register event not on `this.get('element')` but on `this.$('video')`

Comment: At this point, I believe it would be a good idea to make a {{video-player}} component around the `<video>` tag to enclose event handling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer neglected the fact that the `ended` event does not bubble. I leave it around, as it may be useful for people having the same issue with a bubbling event.

Now, as the event does not bubble, you have to handle it manually. Kind of like option 3) of my other post. I would strongly suggest encapsulating that into a component:

```
// video-player/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'video',
  attributeBindings: ['autplay', 'buffered', 'controls', 'crossorigin',
                      'loop', 'muted', 'played', 'preload', 'poster', 'src'],

  init: function () {
    this._super();
    this._events = {};
    Object.keys(this.events).forEach(function (name) {
      this._events[name] = function (evt) { Ember.run(this, this.events[name]); };
    }, this);
  }

  registerHandlers: Ember.on('didInsertElement', function () {
    var el = this.get('element');
    Object.keys(this._events).forEach(function (name) {
      el.addEventListener(name, this._events[name], false);
    }, this);
  }),
  unregisterHandlers: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function () {
    var el = this.get('element');
    Object.keys(this._events).forEach(function (name) {
      el.removeEventListener(name, this._events[name], false);
    }, this);
  }),

  events: {
    play: function (evt) { this.sendAction('play'); },
    ended: function (evt) { this.sendAction('ended'); }
    // add more at will
  }
});
```

You should be able to use it like this:

```
{{#video-player id="externalVideo" controls loop ended='videoEnded'}}
  <source src="../assets/videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
{{/video}}
```